# nodemon - watch the original script, not the current dir

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I have scripts that are in my `$PATH` that work by operating on files present in the current directory.

I'd like `nodemon` to monitor `__dirname`, not `.`.

How?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but have you tried `nodemon --watch your_dir script.js`?

Comment: I think you understood it just fine. That's probably what I should use. But it's sort of lame having to explicitly specify the dir that the script is in.